# How to select unique list out of collection of lists?

Tags: c#

I have a collection of `IList` where I can see duplicate set of `List` in it. How can I just select a unique list?

`IList` parameters,

```
IList<OrderItemModifier> Modifiers; 

public class OrderItemModifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MenuAnswerId { get; set; }
    public int DatabaseId { get; set; }
    public int Plu { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string SpecialInstructions { get; set; }
    public string ModifierDescription { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

Now there is a scenario where `Modifiers` has two entries (as shown below) where both of them are same and I want to select unique out of it.

Example, `Modifiers` has two entries where [0] & [1] are exact same and I just want to pick unique one (here [0]).

```
[0] {OrderItemModifier} - Same values
[1] {OrderItemModifier} - Same values
```

I've tried following but it didn't work.

```
1.  
var uniqueModifiersList = newItem.Modifiers.Distinct().ToList();

2. 
HashSet<OrderItemModifier> uniqueModifiersList = new HashSet<OrderItemModifier>();
foreach (OrderItemModifier item in newItem.Modifiers)
{
    uniqueModifiersList.Add(item);
}

3.
HashSet<OrderItemModifier> uniqueModifiersList = new HashSet<OrderItemModifier>(newItem.Modifiers);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Override `Equals` on `OrderItemModifier` and your first way will work.

Comment: Try overriding Equals and GetHashCode (and ideally implementing `IEquatable<OrderItemModifier>`) - otherwise no two objects will ever be equal...

Comment: Do you intend to check for reference-equality or value equality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var filteredList = Modifiers
  .GroupBy(modifier => modifier.Id)
  .Select(chunk => chunk.First());
```

Comment: Add `.Select(chunk => chunk.First());`

Answer (score 0):

You should override Equals and GetHashCode meaningfully, in this case to compare the ID:

```
public class OrderItemModifier
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var typedObj = obj as OrderItemModifier;
        return typedObj != null && typedObj.Id = this.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Id;
    }
}
```

Now you can use Distinct:

List uniqueIDs = myList.Distinct().ToList();

Comment: What's `LinqTest`?  I think you meant to cast to `OrderItemModifier`.